# Deduct time complexity from this Recurrence formula?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

I was reading a time complexity calculation related question on SO but I can't comment there (not enough reps).
[What's the time complexity of this algorithm for Palindrome Partitioning?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24591616/whats-the-time-complexity-of-this-algorithm-for-palindrome-partitioning)

I have a question regarding going from 1st to 2nd equation here:

> Now you can write the same expression for H(n-1), then substitute back
>   to simplify:
>
> H(n) = 2 H(n-1) + O(n)        =========>  Eq.1
>
> And this solves to
>
> H(n) = O(n * 2^n)             =========>  Eq.2

Can someone illustrate how he got Eq.2 from Eq.1? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eq 1. is a [recurrence relation](http://www.cs.ucr.edu/~jiang/cs141/recur-tut.txt). See the link for a tutorial on how to solve these types of equations, but we can solve via expansion as below:

```
H(n) = 2H(n-1) + O(n)
H(n) = 2*2H(n-2) + 2O(n-1) + O(n)
H(n) = 2*2*2H(n-3) + 2*2O(n-2) + 2O(n-1) + O(n)
...
H(n) = 2^n*H(1) + 2^(n-1)*O(1) + ... + 2O(n-1) + O(n)

since H(1) = O(n) (see the original question)
H(n) = 2^n*O(n) + 2^(n-1)*O(1) + ... + 2O(n-1) + O(n)
H(n) = O(n * 2^n)
```

Comment: This is incorrect. The correct solution is `O(2^n)` without `n`

Comment: @SalvadorDali - I just looked over the derivation again and it looks ok to me. If you can point out where I made a mistake I'll be happy to update the answer.

Comment: @SalvadorDali: I think I know your mistake. Do not try to verify the solution by "plugging back" the O() terms, as this makes no sense. The equation must be first solved *exactly*, with O() term replaced by symbols; *this* is the solution that you can verify bu plugging back. In this case, solve H(n)=2H(n-1)+K, H(1)=M; the solution is H(n)=(M+K)×2^n-K. Plugging H(n-1)=(M+K)×2^(n-1)-K into the original formula, obtain H(n) = 2((M+K)×2^(n-1)-K)+K = (M+K)×2^n-2K+K = (M+K)×2^n-K = H(n), so the solution is right. Only *now* you can plug M=O(n) and K=O(n), and that yields H(n)=O(n×2^n). Makes sense?

Comment: Please look at my answer. I highly doubt that I have any mistake at all.

Answer (score 1):

We need to homogenize the equation, in this simple case just by adding a constant to each side. First, designate O(n) = K to avoid ealing with the O notation at this stage:

H(n) = 2 H(n-1) + K

Then add a K to each side:

H(n) + K = 2 (H(n-1) + K)

Let G(n) = H(n) + K, then

G(n) = 2 G(n-1)

This is a well-known homogeneous 1-st order recurrence, with the solution

G(n) = G(0)×2<sup>n</sup> = G(1)×2<sup>n-1</sup>

Since H(1) = O(n), G(1) = H(1) + K = O(n) + O(n) = O(n),

G(n) = O(n)×2<sup>n-1</sup> = O(n×2<sup>n-1</sup>) = O(n×2<sup>n</sup>)

and

H(n) = G(n) - K = O(n×2<sup>n</sup>) - O(n) = O(n×2<sup>n</sup>)

Answer (score 1):

They are wrong.

Let's assume that O refers to a tight bound and substitute `O(n)` with `c * n` for some constant `c`. Unrolling the recursion you will get:

[image]

When you finish to unroll recursion `n = i` and `b = T(0)`.

Now finding the sum:

[image]

Summing up you will get:

[image]

So now it is clear that `T(n)` is `O(2^n)` without any `n`

---

For people who are still skeptical about the math:

- solution to [F(n) = 2F(n-1) + n](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=F(n)%20%3D%202F(n-1)%20%2B%20n)
- solution to [F(n) = 2F(n-1) + 99n](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=F(n)%20%3D%202F(n-1)%20%2B%2099n)

Comment: @elhefe added explanation.

Comment: Since in the linked question, H(1) = O(n), and you've changed H to T, b=T(1)=H(1)=O(n). So you actually have O(n)2^n + c(...) = O(n*2^n)

Comment: @elhefe This does not make any sense. How can a function that does not depend on `n` be `O(n)`? How can F(1)` or `F(0)` or `F(15)` be `O(n)`?

Comment: @elhefe is correct: your solution is essentially same as their, only you missed the last step of solving for the _b_.

Comment: @SalvadorDali I'd suggest reading the linked question and asking your question there... I just solved the equations I was given.

Comment: @elhefe and I just say that this does not make any sense. You can't say: here is the function which does not depend on `n` and it is `O(n)` (basically depends on `n`)

Comment: We are not computing the complexity of the algorithm H(n)! H(n) is already a complexity metric. It might have been more proper to be speaking of O(h(n)), and H(n) is just a convenient shortcut for it. This is why I am warning against introducing the big Os into the solution prematurely, as @elhefe did: you can verify your solution in h(n) but not in H(n). Does that finally make sense?